# Should I make my next app in Ruby on Rails or Node.js (meteor)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, meteor

I am conflicted. I haven't worked very much with ruby on rails or node.js (meteor.js/express.js) in the past, but have primarily used php. I'm moving away from it gradually but don't know if i should focus on working with either node or ruby more. 
Any ideas/opinions if I were starting out which language will be the future or more prominent over time and easier to develop productively?
My apologies if i seem a bit rushed, but I am looking to make general web apps that can deploy to mobile as well. I see that meteor.js has this feature built in... but I am obviously open to recompiling for ruby on rails app to work on ios/android as well.
Please don't criticize me, i'm just starting out with these two!

Thanks!

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based, but i will let you this link of meteorpedia named [why Meteor?](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Why_Meteor) it explains very well why should consider using app on future projects, take a look on it

Comment: "So far I've eaten with fingers, but for my next meal I want to try an utensil, so should I use a spoon or a fork?" It's not a matter of opinion - spoon for soup, fork for meat. What are you building? There are things Node can do that Rails can't, and there are things that are easy in Ruby that are painful in JavaScript. In particular, Node is great at holding a bunch of connections at the same time, and holding simultaneous communication between them. Rails can't do that.

Comment: You should also take a good look at [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org)

Answer (score 5):

I would put it down to what you want to achieve.

If your priority is on SEO stick to RoR. Meteor is still young and isn't reliable when it comes to SEO. There is an option to use PhantomJS to render web pages but its not very reliable, in the sense PhantomJS will crash often. The alternative is server side rendering which isn't officially supported yet.

That said, If your goal is to make a Company web app, or Mobile app or anything else really Meteor is the sure way to go.

You can pretty much achieve the same apps as on RoR with the slightly better UX since everything is based on one page. Npm packages can be used on Meteor as well as the atmospherejs repository which unbounds most limitations you could seek to accomplish.

Its also said that its fast to make apps on RoR. The same could be said for Meteor since its even faster (I've used both). The development experience is also smoother owing to

- Hot code reloads when you change files
- Reactive data sources (no meddling with ajax/get requests or sockets)
- Isomorphic code - helps you create server and client side data models with one file instead of a ruby server file and a js client file. The same file can be shared on the client & the server
- An extension of the isomorphism: easier handling of data between the client and server since both sides are javascript. No serialising or deserialising data back and forth. Very helpful with dates in particular (as with other data types too)
- Easy user login system owing to the atmosphere packages.
- Can easily convert a Meteor app into a mobile app for Android or iOS due to the official cordova support.
- No trouble with setting up databases during the development phase as it runs together with the meteor dev environment per-app
- Easier to test in a collaborative environment due to the free `meteor deploy` infrastructure (could argue Heroku does the same for RoR on this one - but it does need a bit of setup with the SSH keys whereas the meteor one doesn't even need you to visit a website to set it up)
- Works on Windows, Linux and OS X. If you have a team project you can share code easily. Meteor also autoinstalls (no `gem install`) the packages and their dependencies automatically (yup no looking for libiconv as you would for certain gem headers). Most binaries are prebuilt on atmosphere.
- No 'callback-hell' on the server side with Meteor owing to it using fibers. So you can have asynchronous or synchronous code.
- Built on NodeJS so you can use NodeJS code/community support from answers like on Stackoverflow in your Meteor app. Best of both worlds.

Ruby is certainly nice and clean & easy to write. But so is Meteor. RoR is a bit more mature so more IDEs support it with autocompletion.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should try a little bit of both and go with the one that gets easier to you or feels more natural. Also, take into consideration, if there are people around you who can help you with one or another.

(There is a joke: the best Linux distro is the one that is running on the computer of your closest Linux-fan friend.)

I must say that Meteor is much younger than Rails, which means a smaller community (but still very active and supportive) and less number of developed 3rd party modules (but Meteor still offers more than 4000 3rd party packages on Atmosphere).

The development environment is very fleshed out for Meteor. Also tooling, like WebStorm, support Meteor. I personally developed multiple Meteor-related extensions for Vim and Sublime Text, too.

Answer (score 3):

So I'm quite biased towards Ruby On Rails since I've been developing in it for a while now, but I believe I have a bias for good reason.

Before I explain more though, I have never developed in Node.js so take everything I say with a grain of salt between them.

First, on future proofing, RoR has been around for a while now and holds some of the highest paying jobs on Web Development. Node.js has high paying jobs as well, but it's fairly new to the scene so RoR wins on reliability of high paying jobs. RoR also is seen as a specialty so the amount of people needing good RoR developers is amazing. I alone have been approached in my area since I'm one of few RoR developers with a lot of experience for my age. Now this doesn't say much about my skill exactly, but RoR developers are sought after a lot right now.

Second, RoR is a joy to code in. It takes a bit to figure out, but once it all starts falling into place, it's amazing how enjoyable it is to work with. Also, RoR is all about designing the RoR way so once you get a few projects going, code reuse is huge. I can get a full blown site up in a few hours now due to how many database setups and models I have pretty baked. That alone is one of my favorite things about RoR.

Finally, the RoR community online is booming. It's been around for a while so there is loads of documentation, but it's also gaining traction in the startup world so it's starting to become important to know a bit about. This means there is a whole new wave of RoR developers happening now that could result in some fantastic new developments for an already awesome framework. Only time will tell.

All in all I would suggest RoR.

Comment: Is Ruby on rails also cross platform?

Comment: It is supported on all major platforms, but development on Linux environments is a lot more enjoyable in my opinion. Also, IDE's such as Ruby Mine make development a breeze with built in servers and functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely consider using MeteorJS if you want to focus on mobile apps.  It works ideally with Phonegap/Cordova.